# My Persian cat pee everywhere at home!

Tags: cats

I have a Persian male cat. Its age is 9 months. I have arranged the potty pot for it. And I change its soil in every week. Also I have put a soft towel type material for pee. Almost from One month, it pees everywhere!!!

That's really hard to clean everything else. It usually finds soft material like bed, sofa, clothes, towel etc for it. When I put clean soft towel for its pee, then it uses it 1-2 times hardly. But after that, it didn't use the same.. Or even, sometimes it didn't use that towel!!

Kindly tell me any solution for this or any reason? That why such change occurs from one month. Its really annoying and unbearable in front of others!!

Your help will be appreciable, thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to pets.se Cleo! There are many many questions on cats peeing outside the box, please check out the ones I have linked above they should help you out :)

Comment: The "soft material" targets are a red flag for a possible UTI, as well as the obvious issues with litterbox cleanliness and everything smelling like a litterbox to a cat. Please consult with your veterinarian, and if you haven't had your cat neutered yet, please schedule that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is spraying. You might want to neuter your tomcat.

Usually starts happening after he is sexually mature.

Answer (score 4):

Cleaning the litter once a week is definitely **not enough**. You have to remove out the "waste" **every day** and replace the litter once a week. If it smells like pee, the cat does not want to pee there again. Towels are no good option for cats, because their natural behavior is to dig a hole, drop their waste inside and bury it until the smell is hidden. Sand or cat litter is more likely to be accepted.

Spraying is another possibility. If the cat makes a puddle below its body, it is urinating. If the cat makes a wet spot behind it (prefered on walls and furnitutre), it is spraying.

Neutering might help against spraying, but it's not guaranteed.
If the cat is actually urinating, it might have a urinary disease like bladder inflammation or urinary stones. You could check it up with a vet.

But from your description it sounds like:

- You don't change litter often enough! A cat will not pee on the same litter / towel if it smells like urine.
- Your cat learned that peeing everywhere is ok. As soon as you change the cat litter **every day**, you should punish it with a water spray bottle if it tries to urinate anywhere outside the litter box.