# How do I clean cat urine on my smartphone?

Tags: cats, cleaning, urination

My cat peed on the bed and some of the urine got on my phone. I was trying to google ways to clean it but the results I see are for carpets, couches, etc. Not for electronic devices like smartphones. I don't want to accidentally damage my phone.

As far as I know it didn't get soaked in the pee but it does smell strongly of it. The phone seems to be working fine.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE. Maybe you should search for "smelly fluid" instead. This site is for well being and care for pets, not for phones. So there is no guarantee, someone had the same experience, or a similar phone...

Comment: I think that this question should be moved to Lifehacks?

Comment: You'll probably want some kind of enzyme cleaner to break down the smelly compounds, but I agree that this question is about the well-being of your phone, so better suited for a stackexchange focused on electronics.

Comment: Please have a look at https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/20872 and further questions linked on top. If your cat suddenly stops using the litter box, it may be displeased with the litter box (too dirty, litter is too coarse or the edges are too high to get in and out comfortably) or it may have an urinary tract infection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I acknowledge that my question probably does not fit here completely. If people feel it needs to be deleted then so be it. And regarding the cat not using the litter box, she is scheduled for a vet visit soon so no worries.

That being said, in case this happens to someone else, I ended up using baby wipes to completely clean my phone and the case and after I let it dry, the smell was gone.

Comment: A better option to this is something like Nature's Miracle wipes, which are an enzymatic cleaner. You may *think* the smell is gone, but it's unlikely it's fully been broken down, which means it may very well return.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AllisonC I will look into this product as well

Comment: Even if the smell does not return according to a human nose, it might still be forever marked as an object that needs the occasional urination according to a feline nose... :)